# Copy Vite build files to another folder after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, copy, vite

I have a several Vue projects near the wordpress project.
The older project is based on **Webpack**, the newer one is based on **Vite**.

The file structure looks like this:

```
project
  |
  |__vue-project-webpack
  |   |
  |   |__dist
  |
  |__vue-project-vite
  |   |
  |   |__dist
  |
  |__wordpress project
      |
      |__target
```

The dist folder files from Vue are used in `wordpress/target` folder.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to copy build files from Vite `dist` folder to `target` folder of the WP project. It is now done manually.

In webpack project the `fsTest` lib does the job:

```js
configureWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.output.filename = 'js/webpack-[name].js';
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/webpack-[name].js';
    }
    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,
      {
        apply: (compiler) => {
          compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', () => {
            const webpackAssets = [
              {
                source: `${PATHS.dist}/js/webpack-app.js`,
                dest: `${PATHS.wpAssets}/js/webpack-app.js`,
              },
            ];
            const options = { overwrite: true };
            webpackAssets.forEach(item => {
              fsTest.copy(item.source, item.dest, options, err => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Copy build success!');
              });
            });
          });
        },
      },
    ];
  },
```

I can't find similar approach in Vite because all the copy files plugins run before build and not after.
Is there a way to execute them after the build is finished?

Also these files generates with a hash name, like `index-d8c14379.css`. How can I change them to those names, for example to `vite-app-styles.css`?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, I think we can simply use a copy command after building successfully. To run it automatically, you can put it in the build scripts of package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vite build && cp dist/* -r '../wp/target'",
  },
```

For your second question, I don't really understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on it?

**Updated for the second question**

First, the hash in each file is very good. It keeps your website up to date. So I think you should think about it a little more before removing it.

Second, if you want to remove the hash, there is a way [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/378#issuecomment-768816653). You can tweak the vite config a little

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), eslint()], // ignore this one
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Your answer perfectly suits me, thank you!

About the second part - Vite generates dist files like this:
`index-13d21e52.js`
`index-449c686d.css`

I'm not sure, but I think that this hash after `index-` is different every time. Is it possible to rename generated file to something like `myJsFile.js` and `myCssFile.css`? Hope I described it a bit better

Comment: I tried to add the && cp but I get cp is not recognized commad :( ```vite build && cp dist/* -i '../data'```

Comment: @StefanoMartini I think you didn't have cp installed. You can install it globally by this command `npm i -g cp`, or using another env that already had cp installed